# Rails 3.2 CarrierWave always saving image as open-uri

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, carrierwave, open-uri

I am using Rails 3.2.13 and Carrierwave 0.9.0.

I am extracting many pictures with this gem. I've succeed to download all these pictures, unfortunately their name are always : "open-uriXXXXXX".

I would like to have exactly the original name of these pictures.
Do you have any idea ?

Here is the code in my controller to download a picture :

```
var_bis = 'URL' + line['illustration_url']
image_bis = open(var_bis)
p.illustration.store!(image_bis)
```

Furthermore, I have not changed the original file of my uploader except for the directory store.
Thanks a lot,

EDIT :

My uploader file :

```
class ImageUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  storage :file

  def store_dir
    "My_path_to_save_images"   
  end

end
```

**EDIT FINAL :**

Here is the answer to add in the controller :

`f=open(File.basename(var_bis), 'wb')

f << open(var_bis).read

p.illustration.store!(f)`

Comment: can you list your uploader file here plz?

Comment: My uploader file in my edit part.

Comment: check if you have override filename method

Comment: No I havn't. It is always saving as open-uri. But I havn't used the filename method ...

Comment: can you try def filename original_filename end? This will clear if some other code is overriding this method.

Comment: There is no difference ...

Comment: @user2508368 Why cant you just do `[your_object].remote_url= [url_to_image]` and carrierwave do the rest